# In python 2.x should I call object.__del__?

Tags: python, subclass, destructor, python-2.x

In Python 3.x all classes are subclasses of `object`. In 2.x you have to explicitly state `class MyClass(object)`. And, as I'm trying to write as much 3.x compatible code as possible, I'm subclassing `object`.

In my program, I'm using the `__del__` method, and I wanted to know if I should be calling `object.__del__(self)`, or if that's magically taken care of?

Thanks,
Wayne

EDIT:
It appears there is some confusion what I mean - in the documents it states:

> If a base class has a `__del__()` method, the derived class’s `__del__()` method, if any, must explicitly call it to ensure proper deletion of the base class part of the instance.

So I wanted to know if I needed:

```
def __del__(self):
    object.__del__(self)
```

or some suitable alternative.

Comment: Why on earth are you calling `__del__`?  What possible purpose can this serve?  Why not use the `del` statement and avoid this?  Are you doing some `super( class, self ).__del__()`?  Why?

Comment: @S.Lott, the documentation for `__del__` mentions calling a superclass's `__del__`, and I couldn't find any information about using `__del__` in conjunction with subclassing `object`. I didn't think of just introspecting `object` to find out that it doesn't have a `__del__`, but now I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `object` doesn't actually have a `__del__` method, so no, you don't need to call it.

```
>>> object().__del__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'object' object has no attribute '__del__'
```

Answer (score 4):

`__del__` isn't meant to be called.  Destructors are executed automatically when the object has no more references and is collected.

Inversely, you don't call `__init__`, but is taken care of automatically on object creation.  Calling `__del__` won't destruct the object and doing so may actually lead to unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 4):

Check http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization and http://docs.python.org/library/gc.html#module-gc.  You don't need to call the `__del__` method on your object, because the garbage collector is supposed to do it for you.  Just write a correct `__del__` method and python will take care of it for you.

Comment: It appears I didn't communicate clearly - I'm not calling *my* object's `__del__` - I (hope) I clarified my question in the edit.