# How to use __del__ in a reliable way?

Tags: python, destructor, python-2.4

I have learned that python [does](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__) [not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481488/how-to-call-the-del-method) [guarantee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199653/in-python-2-x-should-i-call-object-del) that `__del__` is called whenever an object is deleted.
In other words, `del x` **does not** necessarily **invoke** its destructor `x.__del__()`.

If I want to ensure proper object cleanup, I should use a [context manager](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7.2/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers) (in a `with` statement).

I know it's stupid, but for a couple of reasons (please don't ask why) I am tied to a system with Python 2.4; therefore context managers are out of question (they were introduced in Python 2.5)

So I need a an alternative solution, and hence my question: are there best practices that would help me to use `__del__` reliably? I am thinking in the direction of *"if python provides such functionality, there must be a way it can be efficiently used (I'm just to stupid to figure out how)",,,*

Or I am just being naive, should forget about `__del__` and move on to a completely different approach?

Comment: The problem is that Python *does* provide that functionality, but sadly not in a version that you have.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In short: No, there is no way to ensure it gets called.

The answer is to implement context managers yourself. A `with` statement roughly translates to:

```
x.__enter__()
try:
    ...
finally:
    x.__exit__()
```

So just do it manually. It is a little more complex than that, so I recommend reading [PEP 343](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) to fully understand how context managers work.

One option is to call your cleaning up function `close()`, and then in future versions of python, people can easily use [`contextlib.closing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing) to turn it into a real context manager.

Comment: Thanks @Lattyware, I will have a look at this PEP.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of `__del__`, give your class a method called something like `close`, then call that explicitly:

```
foo = Foo()
try:
    foo.do_interesting_stuff()
finally:
    foo.close()
```

For extra safety and forward-compatibility, have `__exit__` and `__del__` call `close` as well.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to avoid (call the destructor (or equivalent) explicitly). Unfortunately it may be the only way to go. Thanks!