# How to reliably trigger __del__ method of object?

Tags: python-3.x, object

I would like to reliably call the `__del__` method of an object immediately when it gets deleted. I am aware that this has been asked for [python 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352480/how-to-use-del-in-a-reliable-way), but the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__) of python 3 claims that the `__del__` method is called when the reference count reaches 0. However, this does not seem to be the case with my program

```
import time

class MyClass:
    object_list = []
    def __init__(self):
        MyClass.object_list.append(self)
        print("object initialized")
    def __del__(self):
        print("executing cleanup steps")
        MyClass.object_list.remove(self)

a = MyClass()
b = MyClass()
c = MyClass()
print(len(MyClass.object_list))
del b
time.sleep(1)
print("sleep finished")
print(len(MyClass.object_list))
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##hVC9CsIwEN7zFEenZCmIm@Dk7BOIhDS96kmahuYq6svX/iktit4S7vh@E@58rvy6bakMVc3AVKIQ1pkYYX/f9e9GQDdVdkHL2lFk2MLhOBxzLEBr8sRay4iuUCO4n4mdzoipCQF9PiLfwFCTZ5mMOOjFyDh6YJ6omUmO7tNjouINbcPkT2AdGt8EiIwhJupnmBrL6opTGGG6VhNKKpEtNrvYRlOHXn5RVUp0SSET/Uem0SEGuXpxkmGHousYz0O/P1pt@wQ)

What I want to achieve is to remove `b` from the `object_list` immediately when it is destroyed and also make the variable `b` inaccessible. So simply calling `b.__del__()` is not enough, I would need to also render `b` inaccessible.

Note: running first `b.__del__()` and then `del b` will lead to complaints when exiting the python interpreter.

Interestingly enough, a very similar program seems to call `b.__del__()` immediately when `del b` is executed.

```
import time

class MyClass:
    counter = 0
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        print("object initialized")
        MyClass.counter+=1
    def __del__(self):
        print("executing cleanup steps")
        MyClass.counter-=1

a = MyClass(5)
b = MyClass(6)
c = MyClass(7)
print(MyClass.counter)
del b
time.sleep(1)
print("sleep finished")
print(MyClass.counter)
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##dVBBjsIwDLz7FVZPjXa3AiFYCYnTnnlDlaYuZBXSqHER8PmShIAqtOuLNePJjB135WNvV9OkT64fGFmfCEAZ6T3urz@xbwFDqX60TAPucJFwSx3Wtbaa67r0ZLpPPEszknjIY0W2SmR4lfpr5AZtuSz65pcUY3TR0ugbtYV4aXJ8lZM/dstZcEsm584CsytdSI2s7QGVIWlHh57J@f@tv4I1yLBk5su1gGYGNwLUDH4LeCS92QgIW2ED8Q8rb4hcuXxKi4SxC6f6Yzrzb4tpugM)

**EDIT**
@Pranav Hosangadi pointed out that there is still a reference to the object in the `object_list`. What a shameful oversight of mine. Now I came up with a workaround by calling first `b.__del__()` and then `del b`, but it is a two step process. I would like to have it in one step, if possible.

```
import time

class MyClass:
    object_list = []
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        MyClass.object_list.append(self)
        print("object initialized")
    def __del__(self):
        print("executing cleanup steps")
        try:
            MyClass.object_list.remove(self)
        except:
            pass

a = MyClass(1)
b = MyClass(2)
c = MyClass(3)
print(len(MyClass.object_list))
b.__del__()
del b
time.sleep(1)
print("sleep finished")
print(len(MyClass.object_list))
```

Comment: _"the documentation of python 3 claims that the `__del__` method is called when the reference count reaches 0"_ `MyClass.object_list` still contains a reference to the object formerly known as `b`, so the `b.__del__` isn't called. In the second case, there is no such reference, so `b.__del__` is called immediately.